# How to populate an SQL Server table with users information from Active Directory?

Tags: vb.net, ssis, active-directory

Using VB.NET in an SSIS package, how do I populate an SQL Server table with the users in multiple Active Directory domains (in the same forest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Script Component (VB.NET) with System.DirectoryServices

Here is a sample logic that import Active Directory users information from one domain into database table with the help of VB.NET in *Script Component* configured as *Source*. This sample was tested in SSIS 2012 but should work in SSIS 2008 and above. This logic will not work in SSIS 2005 because the namespace *`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`* was introduced only in .NET framework 3.5 and SSIS 2005 uses .NET Framework 2.0

- Create an SSIS package. This sample uses SSIS 2012.
- Create an *`OLEDB Connection Manager`* that would connect to the SQL Server database. If you created a data source, add the data source to the package's connection manager tab.
- Drag and drop a *`Data Flow Task`* onto the *Control Flow* tab.
- Double-click the *`Data Flow Task`* to switch to the *Data Flow* tab.
- Drag and drop a *`Script Component`* onto the *Data Flow* tab.
- Check **`Source`** on the *Select Script Component Type* dialog and click OK.
- Double-click the Script Component to open the *Script Transformation Editor*. Click *`Inputs and Outputs`* tab page.
- Rename the Output to ActiveDirectory to give a meaningful name.
- Select Output Columns and click Add Column to add each of the below mentioned columns. This is only to illustrate this example. You might need to add columns of your preference.

#### Column definition within script component

```
Name              Data Type                Length
----------------- ------------------------ ------
FirstName         Unicode string [DT_WSTR]    255
LastName          Unicode string [DT_WSTR]    255
SAMAccountName    Unicode string [DT_WSTR]    255
UserPrincipalName Unicode string [DT_WSTR]    255
```

- After defining the columns, click *`Script`* tab page
- Change the ScriptLanguage to *`Microsoft Visual Basic 2010`*
- On the Solution Explorer, right-click the Script Component project and click *`Add Reference...`*. Add references to the following namespaces.

#### Namespaces to be referenced in the script component

```
System.DirectoryServices
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

- Paste the below VB.NET code into the Script component. Replace the section **`<Your domain name goes here>`** with your appropriate domain name. The code initializes *PrincipalContext* and *PrincipalSearcher* objects in *`PreExecute`* method and then disposes them in *`PostExecute`* method. CreateNewOutputRows method loops through each of the row found in AD to fetch the user attributes information.

#### Script component code (VB.NET)

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Imports System.DirectoryServices

#End Region

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute()> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Dim principalContext As PrincipalContext = Nothing
    Dim principalSearcher As PrincipalSearcher = Nothing

    Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
        principalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "<Your domain name goes here>")
        principalSearcher = New PrincipalSearcher(New UserPrincipal(principalContext))
        MyBase.PreExecute()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        principalContext = Nothing
        principalSearcher = Nothing
        MyBase.PostExecute()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

        For Each principal As Principal In principalSearcher.FindAll()

            Dim entry As DirectoryEntry = TryCast(principal.GetUnderlyingObject(), DirectoryEntry)

            With ActiveDirectoryBuffer
                .AddRow()

                If entry.Properties("givenName").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    .FirstName = entry.Properties("givenName").Value.ToString()
                Else
                    .FirstName = "Unknown"
                End If

                If entry.Properties("sn").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    .LastName = entry.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()
                Else
                    .LastName = "Unknown"
                End If

                If entry.Properties("samAccountName").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    .SAMAccountName = entry.Properties("samAccountName").Value.ToString()
                Else
                    .SAMAccountName = "Unknown"
                End If

                If entry.Properties("userPrincipalName").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    .UserPrincipalName = entry.Properties("userPrincipalName").Value.ToString()
                Else
                    .UserPrincipalName = "Unknown"
                End If

            End With

        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

- Close the Script Transformation Editor.
- Drag and drop an OLE DB Destination onto the Data Flow tab. Connect the Script component to the OLE DB destination to redirect the source output. Select the appropriate OLE DB Connection Manager and the table where the data should be inserted into.

#### Ways to improve this approach:

This sample provides loading information from only one domain. If you have multiple domains, you could stored them in a table. Fetch information of all the domain lists and use *`Foreach Loop Container`* available on the Control Flow to loop through each domain and get the users information using the above mentioned approach. May be there is also a better way to do this within VB.NET.

#### Active Directory User Attributes

You can find the complete list of Active Directory user attributes in the below MSDN link. You need to click the links to find the LDAP-Display-Name.

[*All Attributes (Windows)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is another link that might help to get the user object attributes

[*User Object Attributes (Windows)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This looks like the most appropriate one for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

I went the route of using a query similar to Siva's approach except instead of a linked server query, I use the ADSI provider. [Active Directory SSIS Data Source](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html)

```
SELECT
    distinguishedName
,   mail
,   samaccountname
,   Name
,   employeeNumber
,   objectSid
,   userAccountControl
,   givenName
,   middleName
,   sn
FROM
    'LDAP://DC=domain,DC=net'
WHERE
    sAMAccountType = 805306368
ORDER BY
    sAMAccountName ASC
```

The code in the referenced post will pull all users from a given domain. After converting from NTEXT to TEXT to String, I then use the distinguished name and the DirectoryServices assembly to enumerate all the first order groups for a user via their distinguished name. It does not address nested groups. Conveniently enough, that post covered a 2005 SSIS implementation so the logic is in VB.

Comment: I'm going to try this one as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Linked Server approach:

#### Set up a linked server to connect to Active Directory:

Here is one possible option using *Linked Server* on SQL Server that does not actually require `VB.NET`, if that is an option for you. The queries given below are only for syntax references. Please read the links for proper usage of these SQL Server objects.

You could set up a linked server on SQL Server to connect to the *Active Directory* using `OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services`. Below is a sample script that would set up a linked server and map it with a login that has access to the Active directory.

Usage of [*sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

Usage of [*sp_addlinkedsrvlogin (Transact-SQL)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)

#### Sample script to set up linked server:

```
USE [master];
GO

EXEC    master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
        @server     = N'ADSI'
    ,   @srvproduct = N'ADSI'
    ,   @provider   = N'ADsDSOObject'
    ,   @datasrc    = N'adsdatasource'
    ,   @provstr    = N'ADSDSOObject';
GO

EXEC    master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
        @rmtsrvname     = N'ADSI'
    ,   @useself        = N'False'
    ,   @locallogin     = NULL
    ,   @rmtuser        = N'<User account goes here...>'
    ,   @rmtpassword    = '<Password goes here...>';
GO
```

#### Use OpenQuery to query Active Directory:

You can then use OpenQuery to query the Active Directory for user information. Read the below link on MSDN for more information on how to formulate the query.

[*Search Active Directory - Distributed Query*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

#### Sample script to query Active Directory:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENQUERY
        (           ADSI
            ,   '   SELECT  *
                    FROM    ''LDAP://<OU path goes here...>''
                    WHERE   objectClass = ''user'''
        );
```

#### How to use this data in SSIS package:

You could set up this query as an SQL Server view and then call the view from *OLE DB Source* available on *Data Flow Task* within SSIS package and then redirect the output to an *OLE DB Destination* to populate the database tables.

Comment: This is a great solution, except that I can't use linked servers for my solution.