# Active Directory data into SQL Server using SSIS or SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, active-directory

How can I copy data like firstname, lastname, email from Active Directory into a SQL Server table?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I would use powershell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885337/active-directory-data-into-sql-table

Comment: For an SSIS approach [Active Directory SSIS Data Source](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html)

Comment: And for SO posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927161/how-to-populate-an-sql-server-table-with-users-information-from-active-directory/14928671#14928671 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741312/ldap-query-to-get-disabled-user-records-with-whenchanged-within-30-days/23751008#23751008